# Should there be "the" before the website name search in this sentence?

Tags: definite-article

> The site was ranked #2 and approximately #6 in the website name search and local keyword search respectively on Google.

should there be "the" before "website name search"? or should it "a'? or neither?

Comment: I wonder what "approximately #6" means...

Comment: the site was definitely ranked #2 in the website name search, but I can't accurately recall the result of keyword search, it was between 6~8, that's why I said approximately. Is it in correct usage of "approximately"?

Comment: The word approximately is absolutely fine in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use **the** in this sentence.

The sentence is referencing a particular search engine -- Google, and so it is Google's website name search. It is a particular, definite search engine.

If the search engine did not matter, the sentence would be:

*The site was ranked #2 and approximately #6 in *a* website name search and local keyword search respectively.*

From the [OWL](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/using_articles.html), always a good site for grammar:

> The is used to refer to specific or particular nouns

Answer (score 0):

The Stack Exchange

As it is a name of a specific website, we'd use "the".

"A" means one of many, so is not typically used in proper nouns (names).

Comment: In what way would using 'a' involve proper nouns?

Comment: There does not seem to be any mention of proper nouns in the question. Can you edit to clarify how you see this as helping the OP?

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be 'a'; by using 'the', the writer implies that 'website name search' is something that is used repeatedly in some formal fashion.

If there were a standard set of searches done by some agency, something akin to a political poll, and it did something called a "website name search" as part of its standard, then it would be appropriate to refer to that specific noun with 'the' because it would be referring to a formal thing that was repeated. The formality is less important to the word choice than the repeatability.